# xp_logininfo not showing all members

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I'm trying to loop through all SQL Servers using dynamic query to get all logins and windows groups including subgroups and their logins.

```
exec [server].[master].sys.xp_logininfo 'domain\group', 'members'
```

All is working well. However, in some instances user logins are shown but a subgroup is not; user logins and subgroups are shown but the members that are inside a subgroup are not shown. I cannot say that this is the first nested level of the members are shown only as there is an example when the first nested level subgroup that exists in AD for a group is not shown but the first level users' logins are shown. 
I'm thinking that is all due to permissions but if there could be another reason please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS Docs it returns the next level only. So, the nested groups are not shown.
"If account_name and members are specified, a list of the next-level members of the group is returned."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logininfo-transact-sql